# How to access a prop inside a v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When a prop has the same name as a sub-element in a `v-for` directive. How to access it?

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="{ id, name } in data" :key="id">
           {{name}} and {{props.name}} // Doesn't work, and props name is shadowed here.
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({ data: Array, name: String });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't destructure it:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in data" :key="item.id">
           {{ item.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```